# Given a formal power series $f_1$, can we produce another formal power series $f_2$ suing computer program s.t. $f_1 \circ f_2=f_2 \circ f_1$?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, formal-power-series

**When two formal power series commutes ?**

**Algorithm:**

Let $f = \sum a_n x^n$ and $g = \sum b_n x^n$ be two formal series without constant term. Then
$$
f \circ g = \sum a_n g(x)^n = \sum a_n \left(\sum b_k x^k \right)^n
$$
Now, since
$$
\left(\sum b_k x^k \right)^n = \sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k} x^n
$$
one gets
$$
f \circ g = \sum a_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k}\right)x^n
$$
Therefore $f$ and $g$ commute in the sense of composition of functions if and only if, for all $n$,
$$
a_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k}\right) = b_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} a_{i_1} \dotsm a_{i_k}\right)
$$
**This is the general criteria of commuting two formal power series.**

> My question is about computer programming. That is, suppose we are given a formal power series $f_1(x)$ without constant term, knowing its first $10$ terms or first $10$ coefficients of any finite number of coefficients. Is it possible to write a computer programming like $PARI/GP$ $C++$, Matlab etc. using above algorithm in order to get a formal power series $f_2(x)$ without constant term such that $f_1 \circ f_2=f_2 \circ f_1$ ? At least, can we get the first $10$ terms of coefficients of $f_2(x)$?

Actually I need some example of formal power series which commute each other in the sense of composition of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that your formal series must start at $n=1$ for the composition to be well-defined ? If $f \in xk^*+x^2 k[[x]]$ then why not take $ g=f^{-1}$ ? Please clarify.

Comment: You're right that composition of formal power series requires the constant term to be zero. Once that's taken into account, you have the trivial example $f_2=f_1$ and the slightly less trivial examples where $f_2$ is $f_1\circ f_1$ or a higher iterate of $f_1$.

Comment: @reuns, yes it is my mistake. I mean the formal power series without constant term. But there is a concept that all formal power series may not be invertible as well. How about those cases? Even if it is invertible formal power series over $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, can I explicitly write the first few terms ?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thank you. But how do you verify that $f_2=f_1 \circ f_1$ or its higher iterates works and how do i get the explicitly the first few coefficients of $f_2$ ?

Comment: Compute the $N$ first terms of $f_2(x)^{n+1}= f_2 (x)f_2(x)^n$ from which you'll have the $N$ first terms of $f_1(f_2(x))=\sum_n a_n f_2(x)^n$... It is obvious that $f_2(x)=f_1(f_1(x))$ gives $f_2(f_1(x))=f_1(f_2(x))$ @M.A.SARKAR

Comment: @reuns, ok thank you. I understood that $f=f_1 \circ f_1$ and its iterates works fine. But my question remains same because it is not easy to calculate the first 5 or 10 coefficient of $f_2=f_1 \circ f_1$. Do you think it is easy?  Further there can be other $f_2$ such that $f_2 \circ f_1=f_2 \circ f_1$. So we can not get all by hand. So I think in all cases a computer algorithm may help us to my intuition. What do you think?

Comment: No idea of what you are thinking to. My answer is "please clarify", do you have a concrete problem in mind or are you just trying to understand the composition in $xk[[x]]$

Comment: @reuns, ok I am clarifying as much as possible. I am working with formal power series over $p$-adic field. I want some non-trivial examples of formal power series $f,g$ without constant term such that $f'(0) \neq 0, g'(0) \neq 0$ for both invertible and non-invertible cases.

Comment: @reuns, hopefully I got an answer from a PARI/GP expert, who gave me a positive answer i.e. we can use PARI/GP here.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is any $f_2$ that will work, why not let $f_2(x) = x$? I.e.

$$ f_2(x) = 0 + 1\cdot  x + 0 \cdot x^2 +0 \cdot x^3 +0 \cdot x^4 + \dots$$

Caveats:

- You requested "... using above algorithm ...". This does not use the algorithm.
- I've only checked that this works when considering $f_1$ and $f_2$ as functions; I haven't verified that the sums you provided work out correctly. But given that the sums derive from function composition I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: I am looking a computer program language which will find  any $f_2$ given any $f_1$. Can you suggest any such program?